# Помогите разобраться с фильтром

Tags: java, filter

Есть некая БД в которой лежат комнаты и мне надо выбрать комнаты подходящие по условиям фильтра. В классе `Filter` поля по которым ведётся сравнение.

```
public static Collection findRooms(Filter filter)throws Exception{
        if (filter == null)
            throw new BadRequestException("This filter - " + filter + " does not exist." );

        LinkedList<Room> foundRooms = new LinkedList<>();

        for (Room room : gettingListObjectsFromFileRoomDB(readFromFile(utils.getPathRoomDB()))){
            if (room.getNumberOfGuests() == filter.getNumberOfGuests() || filter.getNumberOfGuests() == 0 && room.getPrice() == filter.getPrice() || filter.getPrice() == 0){
                if (room.getDateAvailableFrom().compareTo(filter.getDateAvailableFrom()) >= 0 || filter.getDateAvailableFrom() == null) {
                    if (room.isPetsAllowed() == filter.isPetsAllowed() && room.isBreakfastIncluded() == filter.isBreakfastIncluded()) {
                        if (room.getHotel().getCountry().equals(filter.getCountry()) || filter.getCountry() == null && room.getHotel().getCity().equals(filter.getCity()) || filter.getCity() == null) {
                            foundRooms.add(room);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return foundRooms;
    }
```

Выборка по фильтру работает не корректно. Когда подставляю значение даты `DateAvailableFrom` и буленовские значения `PetsAllowed` и `BreakfastIncluded` в фильтр, то по ним выборка идёт нормально. Но когда добавляю `NumberOfGuests`  то в результате поиска всё равно выдаются все комнаты, а не те в которых значение `NumberOfGuests` равно значению указанному в фильтре. Когда добавляю в фильтр значения `Price`, `Country`, `City`, то комнаты находятся правильно. Если ввожу  `Country`и `City`, то находит комнаты из одной страны, но при этом не учитывает город, то есть выдаёт комнаты из всех городов. Если `Country` ставлю значение `null`, а `City` значение города, то находит комнаты по заданному городу. Вот такие не стыковки.
Где у меня ошибка ? Долго уже сижу над этой проблемой и самому разобраться не получается. И ещё такой момент, когда в фильтре вместо даты ставлю `null`, чтобы поиск не брал во внимание дату, то выскакивает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Date.getMillisOf(Date.java:958)
    at java.util.Date.compareTo(Date.java:978)
    at dz_lesson35_36.dao.RoomDAO.findRooms(RoomDAO.java:66)
    at dz_lesson35_36.demo.DemoRoom.main(DemoRoom.java:47)
```

Подскажите, как исправить мои недочёты ?

Comment: Сравнение с null в конструкциях || лучше ставить на первое место:
Например вместо 
(room.getDateAvailableFrom().compareTo(filter.getDateAvailableFrom()) >= 0 || filter.getDateAvailableFrom() == null)
используйте 
(filter.getDateAvailableFrom() == null || filter.getDateAvailableFrom().compareTo(room.getDateAvailableFrom()) <= 0)

Comment: Не решает проблему ((

Comment: NPE при null-дате остался?
Да и про скобки вам не зря писали:
Первое условие у вас примерно так:
`A || B && C || D `
Если ничего не путаю то оно равнозначно
`A || (B && C) || D `
А вам надо
`(A || B) && (C || D)`

Comment: NPE остался (( , а со скобками сейчас ещё раз проверю.

Comment: Александр Поташев, спасибо за помощь. Ваши пояснения очень помогли. Теперь всё работает и NPE не выбрасывается.

Answer (score 0):

Расставь скобки

```
if ((room.getNumberOfGuests() == filter.getNumberOfGuests()) || (filter.getNumberOfGuests() == 0 && room.getPrice() == filter.getPrice() || filter.getPrice() == 0)){
```

Что касается null даты, то в фильтре сделай проверку типа

```
if(date != null){

}
```

Comment: Что-то расстановка скобок ничего не даёт, вообще. Тот же результат получается.

Comment: Значит трудность где-то за пределами предоставленного когда

Comment: За пределами предоставленного кода только файл с комнатами и класс Filter, в котором указаны поля ( параметры ) по которым производится поиск. В фильтре может быть указан один параметр или все или какие угодно, на выбор пользователя. В этих местах логики нет ни какой. Проблема в условии поиска, где я и не могу разобраться.